# Fill a blank cell next to a non-blank cell in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for VBA code to fill blank cell in a column below to a non empty cell in a range of data.

```
CploumnJ  ColoumnK        ColoumnL
1           10            K
1           20            L
1           30            M
Blank Cell  Blank Cell    Blank Cell
2           15            A
2           25            B
2           35            C
2           45            D
Blank Cell  Blank Cell    Blance Cell
```

and the data goes on... to number of rows variable each time).

I want to update "AAA" in all blank cell in Column "K" till the end of data (Column K only J and L don't have any update).  Can some one help to post the VBA code.

I created the below code, but it goes beyond length of Column B.  If I have 20 rows in the data, it goes up to 350 rows which is not warranted

```
Sub fillbankaccount()
    Columns("K:K").Select.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select 
    Selection.Value = "AAA"
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear what you are asking for. What have you tried already? Show your attempts and current **code**.

Comment: Hi Mehow, I edited my question, please see if it make sense

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
Sub fillbankaccount()

    On Error Resume Next
    Range("K1:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "AAA"

End Sub
```